# Ant Build-Script how to check for root privileges

Tags: ant, build-script

How can I check for root privileges with an Ant build script? I tried doing it with the shellscript task like

```
<shellscript shell="bash">
    if [[ `whoami` != 'root' ]]; then
        echo "You need to be root to install ooplss";
        exit 1
    fi
</shellscript>
```

But this won't stop the execution of the script.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [shellscript](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/shellscript.html) task is an extension of the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task. You should be able to specify `failonerror` to make the build process fail if the script fails:

> failonerror:  Stop the buildprocess if
>   the command exits with a return code
>   signaling failure. Defaults to false.

```
<shellscript shell="bash" failonerror="true">
    if [[ `whoami` != 'root' ]]; then
        echo "You need to be root to install ooplss";
        exit 1
    fi
</shellscript>
```

It should however be possible to do without a shell script; the following is untested:

```
<fail message="You need to be root to install ooplss">
 <condition>
   <not>
     <equals arg1="root" arg2="${user.name}"/>
   </not>
 </condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the java property `user.name`:

```
<target name="checkroot">
  <condition property="isroot">
    <equals arg1="${os.user}" arg2="root"/>
  </condition>
</target>
<target name="dostuff" depends="checkroot" unless="isroot">
...
</target>
```

Since ant 1.7 you can also use `<scriptcondition>` to do something clever in a script instead of the `<equals>` above

Answer (score 0):

a straight approach with [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <fl:when test=" '${user.name}'.toupper eq 'ROOT' ">
    <!-- your tasks go here.. -->
  </fl:when>
</project>
```